# unable to register onclick with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to to register `onclick` for `div`, but it's not working. Instead, the cal to `alert` is getting triggered when page is loaded.

```
function print()
{
    alert(' div clicked..');
}


var divElement = document.getElementById("content");
divElement.addEventListener("onclick", print());
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/SwrVg/1/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you *do not* need the `on` prefix. And `print` should **not** have empty parenthesis. An empty parenthesis will cause the function to execute, and its return value *be passed as the **function*** to call - which is *not* what you want.

Try this:

```
var divElement = document.getElementById("content");
divElement.addEventListener("click", print);
```

Here's an [updated working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwrVg/3/).

---

**Edit:** Per [Ian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110016/unable-to-register-onclick-with-addeventlistener/16110043#comment23005966_16110043) below, here's a helper function for backwards compatibility with certain version of Internet Explorer.

```
function AttachEventListener(element, event, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    } else {
        alert('Invalid element specified for AttachEventListener');
    }
}
```

Instead of using `divElement.addEventListener("click", print)`, you would do `AttachEventListener(divElement, 'click', print)`.

The *main* reason to use the helper function is because older versions of Internet Explorer *do not* have `addEventListener`, and **do** require the `on` prefix when using `attachEvent`. This helper function will save you the trouble of doing the feature-check yourself on every event binding.

Comment: Note: `attachEvent` (which isn't part of this question) **does** require the "on" prefix

Comment: @Jesse Oh you don't have to, I just wanted it to be known for anyone that sees this question/answer. That may or may not be the reason why this question happened (or because of the usual setting `.onclick` property of elements).

Comment: @Ian Yup, I understood what you wanted to accomplish, but I've done it for all those future users too. =)

Comment: @Jesse Haha sounds good, I thought your answer was good before, but I'd say it's better now :)

Answer (score 4):

You should write it like this:

```
divElement.addEventListener("click", print);
```

`print` is a variable that points to your function.

`print()` is the *output* of that function. (it has no output, so it's `undefined`)

Since you want to assign the function, not the output, you must use `print`.

Also, you don't need the `on` prefix.

Presto: http://jsfiddle.net/AEjKC/